# Как подружить свойства display, opacity и transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

Мне нужно, чтобы элемент плавно появлялся из ниоткуда. Его изначальные стили:

```
transition: 'all 1s linear';
display: 'none';
opacity: 0;
```

При клике он должен появляться и становиться в:

```
display: 'block';
opacity: 1;
```

В моем коде он появляется резко и не плавно совсем:

```
this.trigger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
           this.popupWindow.style.display = 'block';   
           this.popupWindow.style.opacity = 1;        
 });
```

Я нашёл решение и спрятал прозрачность в setTimeout с 1/1000 долей секунды (и он действительно появляется плавно, как написано в css-свойстве transition):

```
this.trigger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
           this.popupWindow.style.display = 'block';   
           setTimeout(()=>{this.popupWindow.style.opacity = 1}, 1); 
});
```

Хоть моё решение и работает, оно эстетически мне не нравится и я хотел бы найти более правильный, элегантный и лаконичный вариант решения этой проблемы. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: В js-коде между display и opacity поставьте строчку `this.popupWindow.offsetWidth;`

Comment: вот тут есть все что тебе нужно для решения 2 часа но очень полезных https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TLnIQbk5qo

Comment: Используйте событие transitionend. По его наступление делайте display :none

Comment: @Дмытрык во-первых, автору нужно наоборот, а во-вторых, transitionend срабатывает не всегда и setTimeout надёжнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть возможность display: none/block заменить на height: 0/X
Можно решить с помощью transition и подмены классов

```js
window.onload = () => {
  var btn = document.getElementById('toggleBtn');
  var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (elem.classList.contains('hide')) {
      elem.classList.remove('hide');
      elem.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      elem.classList.add('hide');
      elem.classList.remove('show');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#elem {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#elem.hide{
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease, height 0s ease 2s;
}

#elem.show{
  transition: opacity 2s ease, height 0s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="show">TEXT</div>
<button id="toggleBtn">togglr</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю, это решение моего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="div-1">
  OPEN
  <div class="div-2">XEXE</div>
</div>

.div-2 {
  height: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.div-1:hover .div-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```